# Are document.open and document.close necessary?

Tags: javascript

I'm testing some JavaScript code, and realized that this code...

```
var msg = "Hello, World!";
document.open();
document.write(msg);
document.close();
```

...has the same result as this one:

```
var msg = "Hello, World!";
document.write(msg);
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Much behaviour around *document.write* was established before formal specifications so behaviour is inconsistent and somewhat arbitrary across browsers. However, behaviour is now fairly consistent but there are differences depending on when it's called.

The use of *document.write* is largely discouraged, however it's still useful. It's ubiquitous support means it can be used as a replacement for other techniques if really old browsers need to be accommodated.

#### While a document is loading

If you use *document.write* while the document is loading (e.g. a script element in the document source), then there is no need to call open or close. The document is opened when navigated to and closed when the content has finished loading (i.e. when the *load* event occurs). So as long as all the write statements are executed before *load* occurs, the browser will do the rest.

#### After window *load* event dispatched

Once the document has finished loading (e.g. the *load* event has been dispatched), then a call to *document.write* will first call *clear* which will clear the **entire** content of the document, everything. In this case, not all browsers will automatically call *close* when the call to *write* ends.

Some browsers take a guess and seem to call *close* at some later time (IE?), others (Firefox, Safari) will keep the document open, which might cause some unusual behaviour.

#### Child windows

If you open a child window, e.g. using *window.open*, then write to it from the parent, the write will occur after the page has finished loading so it will clear the document. e.g.

```
function openWindow() {
  var win = window.open('http://www.google.com','','')
  win.document.write(
    '<!doctype html><title>foo</title><div>Here is a div</div>'
  )
  win.document.close();
}
```

In this case you'll never see Google, the call to *write* clears the page the moment it loads and writes the new content.

Also, browsers won't automatically call *close*, you can make subsequent calls to *document.write* and they will append to the existing markup, e.g.

```
// Global
var win;

// Open new window and write to it, don't close    
function openWindow() {
  win = window.open('http://www.google.com','','')

  win.document.write(
    '<!doctype html><title>foo</title><div>Here is a div</div>'
  )
}

// Call some time later, content will be appended    
function writeToWindow(){
  win.document.write(
    '<div>Here is the second div</div>'
  )
}
```

You may see some animation on the tab or window showing that it's still loading.

If, in the above, *openWindow* calls *document.close* before ending, then the subsequent call to *writeToWindow* will clear the document first so that the div is the only element in  the document (along with the mandatory HTML, HEAD and BODY elements automatically added by the browser and probably a TITLE added by error correction).

Therefore, you should call *close* at an appropriate point in this case.

#### The OP

If the following is called during load, then:

```
var msg = "Hello, World!";

// The following has no effect as the document is currently
// loading, therefore already open
document.open();

// Writes to the document
document.write(msg);

// The following has no effect because the window hasn't fired load yet
document.close();
```

So only the *document.write* line does anything useful in this case.

Some play code:

```
var win;

function openWindow() {
  win = window.open('http://www.google.com','','')
  win.document.write(
    '<!doctype html><title>foo</title><div>Here is a div</div>'
  )
  win.document.close();
}

function writeToWindow(){
  win.document.write(
    '<div>Here is the second div</div>'
  )
}
```

Comment: Uhh, now it's clear to me. I've seen this in a book (shown in an example). So, a question for you: Did this book is really good to know about JavaScript? Learning JavaScript / O'Reilly. Thank you dude!

Answer (score 5):

The difference between `open()` and `write()` is that `open()` clears the document so you can write to it. `write()` actually puts stuff in the document.

Explicitly calling `document.open()`/`document.close()` is not necessary as `document.write()` implicitly handles `open()` when the page has loaded and `close()` when finished.

Read the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open)

Comment: If the document has finished loading, then *write* will first call *clear*.

Comment: @RobG Yes, did I not write that? How can I clarify my answer?

Comment: There's probably a bit of context missing, I don't think the full behaviour can be summarised in a couple of lines. What you have covers writing while the document is loading, but it's a bit different say for a window opened by *window.open*, or after the *load* event has occurred.

Comment: Yes, that's right! It's a totally different behaviour when using `window.open()`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. document.open

heres a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/8stv489e/

with this code

```
var msg = "Hello, World! first";
document.write(msg);

var msg = "Hello, World! second";
document.open();
document.write(msg);
document.close();
```

As you can see in the fiddle, the document contents are  overwritten as the document  is reinitialized on `open().`

read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open

> 2. document.close

while `document.close` need not be done anywhere explixitly. document.write automatically closes the stream

> **Edit:**
>
> document.write does not necessarily always close the document if write
>   was called after the document had finished loading (Firefox for
>   example). In that case (e.g. writing to a child window opened using
>   window.open), it's a good precaution to always call close when
>   finished writing.
>   **Contribution @RobG**

Comment: *document.write* does not necessarily always close the document if *write* was called after the document has finished loading (Firefox for example).  In that case (e.g. writing to a child window opened using *window.open*), it's a good precaution to always call *close* when finished writing.

Comment: Yes, according to the `document.write()` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write#Notes): Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling document.open() will automatically perform a document.open call. Once you have finished writing, it is recommended to call document.close(), to tell the browser to finish loading the page.