# Replacing the entire HTML document of a website from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome extension that blocks websites, but not using the Chrome built-in blocking methods. The reason for customising, is I need to display a custom block page for each website blocked - the same template, with details as to why this particular site is blocked.

In my `content.js` file I store a full HTML template of a 'this site is blocked' page in a var called `template` (as I couldn't figure out loading it from a file inside the Extension, I'm a Python coder by day...). The manifest contains a large list of URLs, so if the content.js script has been loaded, this site should be blocked (or checked to see if locally the user has allowed it with 'allow anyway'). If a site should be blocked, the only thing I've gotten to work is:

```
var template = `<html>...full web page template removed...</html>`;

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getSite", site: window.location.host.toString()}, (response) => {
  console.log(response.data);

  document.body.innerHTML = renderTemplate(template, response.data);
});
```

The renderTemplate function just takes the HTML and does some find + replace with the response.data - which is data about the URL, fetched from a background script that's simply a .js file with a massive dictionary.

The problem is it obviously only replaces the `<body>`, and the websites CSS affects the block page. Is it possible to replace the entire page contents? Trying to replace the `document.body` entirely throws `The provided value is not of type 'HTMLElement'.`

I'm still learning both JS + extension development, any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use document.write

The problem that you are running into is that you are replacing the body, but not the head (or any <script>s that reside outside of the body).

To replace all html, you want to use document.write. Depending upon how you want to overwrite, you may want to [call document.open and document.close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854494/are-document-open-and-document-close-necessary).

#### Example

An example replacing all html is shown below:

```
newHTML = `<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Simple HTML Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is a very simple HTML document</p>
    <p>It only has two paragraphs</p>
  </body>
</html>`

document.open()
document.write(newHTML)
document.close()
```

#### Verification

Using [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (should be Options > More Tools > Developer Tools), we can navigate to the console and get the content

```
-> document.documentElement.outerHTML
<- html 
   <html><head>
   <title>
   A Simple HTML Document
   </title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p>This is a very simple HTML document</p>
   <p>It only has two paragraphs</p>

   </body></html>"
```

This [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/epk1mghu/5/) shows what this looks like, and replaces the CSS background.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, this is exactly what I needed. I had tried overwriting all manner of properties of document, but hadn't thought about write! Thanks again!